# How can I connect via SSH (Putty) to my VMWare machine (Ubuntu)?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtual-machine, ip, vmware-workstation

I'm trying to connect to my VMWare (Workstation 7.1.3) machine (Ubuntu Lucid) via SSH. I've read through some [other post](https://serverfault.com/questions/38870/how-to-connect-debian-vmware-from-putty-on-the-same-pc)s, but I can't figure this out. I ran `ifconfig`, and got a `inet addr:` and `Bcast` and `Mask:` which appear to be IP addresses. If I try to connect via Putty SSH to any of those addresses, it doesn't work. I also tried connecting to my IP address (from whatismyip.com).

Note: This is all taking place on the same desktop computer.

Comment: Can you ping the `'inet addr:'` of your VM from  the desktop computer ?

Comment: It is important that the Network Adapter in the VM settings be changed to the `Bridged` mode.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Is the package openssh-server installed on your Ubuntu VM? You'll need that package if you want to connect to it by SSH.

You can make sure by opening a terminal (through VMWare's console, I guess) on Ubuntu and running:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Answer (score 24):

*How to do it?* Here are the complete steps. 
Just follow these steps:

> 1. In the terminal use command: **`sudo apt-get install openssh-server`**
> 2. Switch to bridged networking mode, make that change in the Virtual Machine Control Panel **(Edit > Virtual Machine Settings)**
> 3. reboot the VM
> 4. Run "ifconfig" command in terminal & get "inet addr" of "eth0"

*That's all* ! Now use this IP to connect via ssh (I use Putty in my Windows 8)

Comment: Why switch to bridged mode?

Answer (score 10):

If the network is configured properly - either with port-forwarding or as "bridged" and SSH is still not working (from the question text that seems to be the case), then it's either that ssh is not installed or not running. For example, ssh is not running by default on Kali although it's already installed. You'll have to run it yourself.

To start the ssh service:

```
service ssh start
```

Comment: This is as valid answer as the approved one. If the network is configured properly - either with port-forwarding or as "bridged" and SSH is still not working (from the question text that seems to be the case).
Than, it's either that ssh is not installed or not running.
For example, ssh is not running by default on Kali although it's already installed. You'll have to run it yourself.

Comment: As a person who only uses Linux occasionally this is the sort of thing that always trips me up.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the SSH is allowed or not allowed in your firewall settings, if you use Linux with a GUI it might be like this:

Click on system -> Administration -> security level and firewall

Click on firewall option tab, enable it, apply and save.

Here you can allow telnet and https as well.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm on Workstation 15, and as Rajat said:

1. In the terminal use command: sudo apt-get install openssh-server
2. Make sure it is NAT in network adapter settings of VM
3. reboot the VM
4. Run "ifconfig" command in terminal & get "inet addr" of "your_adapter"
5. Open firewall port:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-service=ssh
```

Now you should be able to connect to your vm

Answer (score -1):

On my Centos I connected this way. Setting up internet connection (NAT, BOOTPROTO=DHCP ) , service network restart. Then find out IP - ip a - and use this IP in putty.